# Gnu linker - output section type

Tags: linker-scripts

As far as I know and I have read in linker documentation there are 5 output section types: `NOLOAD, DSECT, COPY, INFO, OVERLAY` but only 2 of them are explained: NOLOAD and OVERLAY. `COPY`, `INFO` and `DSECT` are not explained and everywhere in the internet I can see the same 2 explained and 3 left without a word. Anyone would be so kind to explain what `DSECT`, `COPY` and `INFO` exactly change about output section?

Answer (score 2):

from the official GNU ld documentation (which can be found easily with `info ld`):

```
DSECT
COPY
INFO
OVERLAY
     These type names are supported for backward compatibility, and are
     rarely used.  They all have the same effect: the section should be
     marked as not allocatable, so that no memory is allocated for the
     section when the program is run
```

Comment: I don't see this information from 'info ld' - I see command line usage of ld, but nothing on linker scripts.

Comment: @aneccodeal then you are just looking at the man page (that info displays when the ld documentation isn't installed).